what is probability density and distribution of X?
We have a relation, $0 \leq X \leq  Y$. where X and Y are random variables, and we know the
$$ Y \sim Exp( \eta )$$
I need to find the probability distribution and density of X.
What I tried below, Can anyone please confirm whether it is the correct approach?
$$ P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X \leq x | Y=y) f_{Y}(y) dy $$
based on relation above, $$ P(X \leq x | Y=y) = \frac{x}{y}$$
$$ P(X \leq x) = \int_{x}^\infty \frac{x \ \eta \ e^{- \eta y}}{y} dy $$
$$             = - x \ \eta \ Ei(-x \ \eta) $$
where $ Ei $ is the exponential integral function.
Will density become zero if we differentiate distribution w.r.t y? Is distribution here is type of mixed distribution?

Did you write $0 \leq X \leq  Y$ to say that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,Y)$?

yes, that relation we have.

You could also work with the joint density of $(X,Y)$ like here then find the marginal.


Will density become zero if we differentiate distribution w.r.t y?

Yes, $\dfrac{\partial \mathsf P(X\leq x)}{\partial y} = 0$ because $\mathsf P(X\leq x)$ is not a function of $y$ .
But... Why would you want to do that?
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathsf P(X\leq x)}{\mathrm d x} &= \eta\,\Gamma (0, \eta x)&\qquad&x\in(0,\infty) \\[1ex] & = \eta\int_{\eta x}^\infty t^{-1}\exp(-t)\,\mathrm d t\\[1ex] &= \eta\int_x^\infty y^{-1}\exp(-\eta y)\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$$
That is the incomplete gamma function
And as you can see, this is: $\displaystyle f_X(x) =\int_\Bbb R f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)~f_Y(y)\,\mathrm d y$ .
